# I am using an example fracnsites to make a similar map but I don't under stand the ajax code?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, php, ajax

I am using an example fracnsites to make a similar map but I don't under stand the ajax code? 
The example has js code:

```
var map,
fields = ["gid", "createdby", "featname", "feattype", "status", "acres"], 
autocomplete = [];
function getData(){
$.ajax("php/getData.php", {
    data: {
        table: "fracsandsites",
        fields: fields
    },
    success: function(data){
        mapData(data);
    }
})
```

};

function mapData(data){
    //remove existing map layers
    map.eachLayer(function(layer){
        //if not the tile layer
        if (typeof layer._url === "undefined"){
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });

Here is the getdata php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

//database login info
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '5432';
$dbname = 'sandwikimap2';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'postgis';

$conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
    exit;
}

//get the table and fields data
$table = $_GET['table'];
$fields = $_GET['fields'];

//turn fields array into formatted string
$fieldstr = "";
foreach ($fields as $i => $field){
    $fieldstr = $fieldstr . "l.$field, ";
}

//get the geometry as geojson in WGS84
$fieldstr = $fieldstr . "ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(l.geom,4326))";

//create basic sql statement
$sql = "SELECT $fieldstr FROM $table l";

//if a query, add those to the sql statement
if (isset($_GET['featname'])){
    $featname = $_GET['featname'];
    $distance = $_GET['distance'] * 1000; //change km to meters

    //join for spatial query - table geom is in EPSG:26916
    $sql = $sql . " LEFT JOIN $table r ON ST_DWithin(l.geom, r.geom, $distance) WHERE r.featname = '$featname';";
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

   //database login info
$host = 'localhost';
$port = '5432';
$dbname = 'thndr';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'somepassword';

// connect to database
$conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
    exit;
}
//get the data
$propBoundaries = $_GET['tm4326'];
$flagPoints = $_GET['tmxy4326'];

//turn propertyBoundaries array into formatted string
$propBoundaries = "";
foreach ($propBoundaries as $i => $propBoundary){
    $propBoundaries = $propBoundaries . "l.$propBoundary, ";
}

//get the geometry as geojson in WGS84
$propBoundaryDatastr = $propBoundarystr . "ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(l.geom,4326))";

//turn PropertyPoints array into formatted string
$flagPoints = "";
foreach ($flagPoints as $i => $flagPoint){
    $flagPoints = $flagPoints . "l.$flagPoint, ";
}

//get the geometry as geojson in WGS84
$flagPoints = $flagPoints . "ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(l.geom,4326))";

//create basic sql statement
$sql = "SELECT *
from $propBoundaries.l 
inner join $flagPoints.l
on $propBoundaries.gid=$flagPoints.gid";

echo $sql;

//send the query
if (!$response = pg_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "A query error occured.\n";
    exit;
}

//echo the data back to the DOM
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($response)) {
    foreach ($row as $i => $attr){
        echo $attr.", ";
    }
    echo ";";
}

?>
```

I don't understand what the ajax call in the example is actually doing?  Therefore, I can't write a get data php file to connect to my database.  When the ajax in the example says data: {
            table: "fracsandsites",
            fields: fields
What exactly is table:?  is that some preset thing in ajax?  I am trying to convert my map which runs from a geojson file to coming from a postgis database instead.  Here is what I have so far, but honestly I don't understand what I am doing.

Answer (score -1):

table: "fracsandsites" is table name of DB eg $dbname = 'sandwikimap'

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean?